# Couldn't understand the proof of $M$is a maximal normal subgroup of $G$ if and only if $G/M$ is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $M$ be a maximal normal subgroup of $G$. Consider the canonical homomorphism $\phi : G \to G/M$ Now $\phi^{-1}$ of any nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $G/M$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$ **properly containing $M$**. But M is maximal, so this can not happen, Thus $G/M$ is simple.

I couldn't understand the part in bold. How did we conclude that? , $\phi$ is an homomorphism and we are sure that homomorphisms preserve normal subgroups. A $\phi^{-1}$ of a normal subgroup of $G/M$ will be normal, but I can't conclude that it will properly contain $M$.

I understood the converse.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [The Correspondence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)) : the canonical homomorphism (the projection) $\;\phi\;$ determines a $\;1-1\;$ correspondence between subgroup of $\;G/M\;$ and subgroups of $\;G\;$ **containing the subgroup** $\;M\;$ . This correspondence preserves indexes and normality.

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is **nontrivial**. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G/M$, and $K=\phi^{-1}(H)$. Since $H$ is a group, it must have the identity, so $K$ must contain $M$, since $\phi^{-1}(e) = M$ by the construction of $\phi$. If $H$ is nontrivial, then the pullback of $H$ is a normal subgroup which must contain $M$.