# Decomposition of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

I have a small question about simple groups:

When we're decomposing a group $G$ we take a non-trivial normal subgroup of maximum order $G_1$ so that $\frac{G}{G_1}$ is simple and so on.

But why is $\frac{G}{G_1}$ simple?

I thought it had to do with the fact that $G_1$ is of maximum order, so there is no 'bigger' normal subgroup in $G$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Use the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan okay, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Suppose $G/G_1$ isn't simple. Pick a nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ of it. Now consider the preimage of $N$ in $G$. What can you say about it?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am kind of confused with what you are getting at... If we take a normal subgroup of $G/G_1$, how can we talk about it in $G$?

Comment: By taking the preimage. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G/G_1$ then we can consider $\{ g \in G : g + G_1 \in N \}$. This is, by the isomorphism theorems, a normal subgroup in $G$, containing $N$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan then $G$ would have a normal subgroup with a higher order than $G_1$ thus we reach a contraposition?

Comment: Perhaps also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246306/couldnt-understand-the-proof-of-mis-a-maximal-normal-subgroup-of-g-if-and-o?rq=1) is useful, mentioning the Correspondence Theorem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde we haven't covered that yet in class I believe, but thanks for the link anyways!

Comment: You can see this directly, no problem. You see that several other people here had the same question. I think there are many nice answers given here. Have a look at them.